# UIL (Universal Image Loader) with Google Map Markers: Getting ImageAware is reused for another image. Task is cancelled

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, universal-image-loader

I am populating a map with markers which contain a custom icon that is obtained from the internet and then cached on disk for re-use.

I noticed that this statement appears and that for my `ImageLoadingListener`, the `onLoadingCancelled` is called which results in the marker icon not being displayed and the default Google Marker (the red pointy thing) being displayed.

Below is my code.

Looping through some data and creating markers:

```
for(SomeObject so: listOfObjects){
            Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(so.getLatitude(), so.getLongitude())));
            loadMarkerBitmap(marker,so);
        }
```

The `loadMarkerBitmap` method which sets the marker icon:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(so.getImageURL , new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap categoryIcon) {
                Bitmap combined = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapPin.getWidth(), mapPin.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Bitmap scaledIcon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(categoryIcon,(mapPin.getWidth() * 45) / 100, (mapPin.getHeight() * 45) / 100,true);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(combined);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mapPin,0,0, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(scaledIcon,canvas.getWidth()/2 - scaledIcon.getWidth()/2,(canvas.getHeight()/2 - scaledIcon.getHeight()/2), null);
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(combined));
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {


            }
        });
```

Not sure what is wrong. I have tried creating a strong reference `ImageLoadListener` but encountered the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for the edits @MrUpsidown

Comment: Hi, Can you please share working code. For me first time it was not loading all the images. Thanks

Comment: @KarnakerReddyGaddampally Hello, are you getting the same problem? Can you provide some more details please

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is according to the source code loadImage call cancels previous task for the same image URI e.g. if you started a task with this URL e.g. http://www.google.fr/images/srpr/logo11w.png" and then another whilst the first one was on-going would cancel it

The solution is to use a NonViewAware for example

[image]

This solved for the issue for me, all images display and nothing is cancelled